# Agregar input radio a una tabla de manera horizontal

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tardes, tengo una tabla con algunos datos estático y otros dinámicos que recupera de la BDD tal como se muestra a continuación:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora lo que necesito es agregar algunos input de tipo radio pero de manera horizontal ya que si los agrego verticalmente solo me permitiria agregar una opción de las siete disponibles por toda la tabla y lo que yo necesito es agregar una opción de las 7 pero por usuario. De momento el código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
        <?php

    include 'conexio.php';

    /*
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
    $rs = $conn->query($sql);
    */

    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios");
    $sql->execute();
    $rs = $sql->fetchAll();

    include 'views/asistencia.view.php';

    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border=1>
        <tr>
            <th># Empleado</th>
            <th>Nombre de Empleado</th>
            <th>Asistencia</th>
            <th>Retardo</th>
            <th>Retardo Justificado</th>
            <th>Falta</th>
            <th>Falta Justificada</th>
            <th>Incapacidad</th>
            <th>Cambio de Campaña</th>
        <?php foreach ($rs as $resultado): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $resultado['IdTrabajador']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $resultado['Nombre']; ?></td>
            <!--<td><input type="radio" name="r1" id=""></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="r2" id=""></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="r3" id=""></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="r4" id=""></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="r5" id=""></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="r6" id=""></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="r7" id=""></td> -->
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

El objetivo de mi tabla tiene que quedar de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero tengo que hacer solo una selección por columna y no por fila. El problema de añadir los input radio de esa manera es que solo puedo seleccionar uno por fila y no por columna como yo deseo. Espero mi explicación haya sido clara.

Espero que puedan ayudarme con alguna respuesta. Muchas gracias.

Comment: No se termina de entender la pregunta. **1º**: ¿De dónde viene el valor de los input radio, de una columna del tipo boolean de la BD o de 7 columnas de tipo boolean de la BD? **2º**: ¿Quieres presentar en la tabla algo como marcado/desmarcado según el valor de cada input radio tomado de la BD? **3º**: ¿Ni 1º ni 2º o 1º sí y 2º no, o 1º sí y 2º sí, o 1º no y 2º sí? El hecho es que le faltan datos a tu pregunta...

Comment: Edite la pregunta a ver si se logra entender un poquito más

Comment: De nuevo... pregunta 1: ¿Los input radio se presentan **todos vacíos** en las diferentes líneas o se llenan dinámicamente según valores obtenidos de la base de datos?

Comment: Los input no se llenan dinamicamente, los ocupare para realizar un Insert a una tabla de asistencias en la Base de Datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo haría algo más o menos así:

Usaré un array ficticio para prueba. La cuestión poder identificar cada radio:

- por el nombre: usando `rn`+ el valor de `idTrabajador`+ un número del 1 al 7
- por el id: usando `ri`+ el valor de `idTrabajador`+ un número del 1 al 7

De este modo puedes obtener el valor de cada radio y saber al mismo tiempo a quien pertenece.

**Código PHP: ver [DEMO](http://rextester.com/GSE64468)**

```
<?php 

    $arr = array(
                array("idTrabajador" => "1", "Nombre" => "Pedro"),
                array("idTrabajador" => "2", "Nombre" => "Santiago"),
                array("idTrabajador" => "3", "Nombre" => "Juan"),
            );

    $html='<table border=1>
        <tr>
            <th># Empleado</th>
            <th>Nombre de Empleado</th>
            <th>Asistencia</th>
            <th>Retardo</th>
            <th>Retardo Justificado</th>
            <th>Falta</th>
            <th>Falta Justificada</th>
            <th>Incapacidad</th>
            <th>Cambio de Campaña</th></tr>';

         foreach( $arr as $k=>$v ) {
             $nameRadio="rn".$v["idTrabajador"];
             $idRadio="ri".$v["idTrabajador"];

             $html.='<tr><td>'.$v["idTrabajador"].'</td><td>'.$v["Nombre"].'</td>';
             $html.='<td><input type="radio" name="'.$nameRadio.'_1" id="'.$idRadio.'_1"></td>'; 
             $html.='<td><input type="radio" name="'.$nameRadio.'_2" id="'.$idRadio.'_2"></td>'; 
             $html.='<td><input type="radio" name="'.$nameRadio.'_3" id="'.$idRadio.'_3"></td>'; 
             $html.='<td><input type="radio" name="'.$nameRadio.'_4" id="'.$idRadio.'_4"></td>'; 
             $html.='<td><input type="radio" name="'.$nameRadio.'_5" id="'.$idRadio.'_5"></td>'; 
             $html.='<td><input type="radio" name="'.$nameRadio.'_6" id="'.$idRadio.'_6"></td>'; 
             $html.='<td><input type="radio" name="'.$nameRadio.'_7" id="'.$idRadio.'_7"></td>'; 


         }

    $html.='</table>';


    echo $html;
    ?>
```

Tendrías algo así:

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th># Empleado</th>
    <th>Nombre de Empleado</th>
    <th>Asistencia</th>
    <th>Retardo</th>
    <th>Retardo Justificado</th>
    <th>Falta</th>
    <th>Falta Justificada</th>
    <th>Incapacidad</th>
    <th>Cambio de Campaña</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Pedro</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="rn1_1" id="ri1_1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="rn1_2" id="ri1_2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="rn1_3" id="ri1_3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="rn1_4" id="ri1_4"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="rn1_5" id="ri1_5"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="rn1_6" id="ri1_6"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="rn1_7" id="ri1_7"></td>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Santiago</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="rn2_1" id="ri2_1"></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="rn2_2" id="ri2_2"></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="rn2_3" id="ri2_3"></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="rn2_4" id="ri2_4"></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="rn2_5" id="ri2_5"></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="rn2_6" id="ri2_6"></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="rn2_7" id="ri2_7"></td>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Juan</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="rn3_1" id="ri3_1"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="rn3_2" id="ri3_2"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="rn3_3" id="ri3_3"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="rn3_4" id="ri3_4"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="rn3_5" id="ri3_5"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="rn3_6" id="ri3_6"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="rn3_7" id="ri3_7"></td>
</table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, me sirvio demasiado.